# Is there a way to use std::array with literals, or initializer lists, for comparison, in the same way you can for assignment?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

Example:

```
std::array<float, 3> vec;
```

We can do ...

```
vec = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3};
```

Why can't we also do the following, for comparison?

```
vec == {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}
```

Instead, it appears that we have to do ...

```
vec == std::array<float, 3>({1.1, 1.2, 1.3})
```

... or something similar.

Typedef'ing allows me to do something like ...

```
typedef std::array<float, 3> vector;
vec == vector({1.1, 1.2, 1.3})
```

But is there a way to just do ... ?

```
vec == {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}
```

Can I overload `operator==` to accomplish this? It would seem that the compiler should know to interpret `{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}` as whatever is on the left side of the `==`. It does it for `=`. Why not for `==`?

Comment: Here is another related question: [Can operators be overloaded for initializer_list literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370043/can-operators-be-overloaded-for-initializer-list-literals)

Comment: The selected answer here satisfied my question, though the answer lacked documentary support:
[Compare STL container contents to an initialiser list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781070/compare-stl-container-contents-to-an-initialiser-list)
The documentary support seems to be in this answer: [Initializer lists and RHS of operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators)

Answer (score 1):

Without an alias, you can use `decltype` to convert the list

```
vec == decltype(vec){{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}};
```

You can explicitly call `operator==`, but you cannot implicitly convert the list with the comparison operator.

```
operator==(vec, {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}});
```

The only other option I can think of would be `std::equal_to` but that's uglier:

```
std::equal_to<decltype(vec)>{}(vec, {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}});
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445905/1013719) quotes the standard where it says what an initializer_list **can** be used for, operators are not in that list.

Comment: Yes, but the question is "Why can't we also do the following...". Why, really? What is the fundamental difference between `vec = { 1, 2, 3 }` and `vec == { 1, 2, 3 }`? The fact that `=` is implicitly declared and `==` is user-declared?

Comment: in any case, a special `cmp` function that delegates to `std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), il.begin(), il.end())` would be best, since it avoids the copying.

Comment: Ok, so the linked duplicate answers my question: the assignment operator is explicitly given special treatment by the language specification.